# Casting nvarchar to date with a formatting in SQL-Server

Tags: sql, casting, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio. There is one table in my database containing dates which are stored as nvarchar(255). I want to migrate the data of this table to a new table which I call Converted_Dates and store this data as date. Also, I want them all to be formatted like this YYYY-MM-DD

Currently the Dates table looks like this:

```
**Dates**
15/6/2011 
16/6/2011
2013-03-30
2013-04-16
...
```

I want the new table to look like this:

```
**Converted_Dates**
2011-06-15
2011-06-16
2013-03-30
2013-04-16
...
```

I execute this query but formatting of dates remains the same, only the data type changes from nvarchar(255) to date.

```
    USE [reporting_database]
    GO
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Converted_Dates]
    SELECT
        cast(Dates as date)


        FROM [dbo].[Dates]
    GO
```

Any advice on how to cast the data from the old table to a new one in a preferred format?

Comment: Dates in database are not stored in the format you define. They are stored as just date. Now how the dates are displayed on your server/machine/client depends on your client's setting. You can change it, but it won't change the date format stored in database.

Comment: Try adding `where isDate(dates) = 1` to your existing query.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `date` and `datetime` data type is not stored with format in sql server. If you want to see the date in a different format you can manipulate the way that date and datetime data types are displayed when converted to a `varchar` (or `nvarchar`,`nchar`,`char`) data type using some built in functions.

You should store your dates as `date` data type, and if you can format them at the application level, do so there.  If you must format them in sql, then use [**`convert()`** styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

```
select convert(char(10),getdate(),120)
```

returns: `2017-05-01`

---

In sql server 2012+ you can use [**`format()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
select format(getdate(),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

returns: `2017-05-01`

But `format()` is much slower, take a look here: [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: Downvoted because the question concerns converting strings to dates.  This answer is about converting dates to strings.

Comment: @DanBracuk I address the storage of dates as strings (as in, do not do that), advice on where and when to format them, and how to format them in sql if necessary. OP has already successfully converted the strings to `date` datatype, but wanted the dates to have a "preferred format". I stand by my answer despite the downvote :P

Comment: Clearly one of us did not read the question.  Apparently it was me.  Sorry about that.  Downvote is withdrawn.

Comment: @DanBracuk No worries. Thank you for commenting on why you downvoted, which gave me an opportunity to respond.